# Find longest string in multiple divs (same class)

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of divs, they all have the same class (.Name).

Inside the divs, is some text, in a span.

Now, I want to get the length of the longest string, "measured" across all these divs.

Is it possible to do this, without iterating through them, with foreach?
I was hoping I could simply do

```
$(".Name span").text().length
```

but, of course, this gives me the sum of all the lengths.

Comment: What's the problem with iterating through each div? If you don't want to iterate then I guess you will have to give each div a different class and then manually check their lengths.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but it can give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521245/finding-longest-string-in-array

Comment: you DO have to iterate over divs to know which one is the longest or do it while generating them.

Comment: @amb110395 I suppose there is no real problem with iterating. It would just be much prettier, if I could do it without :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `map()`, although under the hood this is still iterating over all matched elements.

```
var lengths = $(".Name span").map(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).text().length;
}).get();
var maxLength = Math.max.apply(this, lengths);
```

Comment: I think `$.fn.map` returns an array directly; doesn't it?

Comment: @JanDvorak it does indeed, the `get()` I put there was from habit. It works with/without, so I'll leave it.