# Look a head. RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
RegExp: /<(?=(\s*\w+=\w+\s*)*)\1>/
String: <a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b>
```

How do I get ? = to find the maximum possible number of repetitions of a = b? I have cited the regular expression is not working.

Comment: Why do you think this needs a lookahead? ("Look! A head!" is probably not what you wanted to say here...)

Comment: I saw an example of this: `'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'.match/(?=(a+))\1/`
And I decided to do just like with another string

Comment: Maximum possible without advancing the match position? So, what's wrong with a simple `(a=b(?:\s?a=b)*)` ?

Comment: @sln, there may be any string, not necessarily a=b. Maybe p=f or d=s. And we need it look a head.

Comment: Nah, lookahead you don't need. You'd have to show me specifically how a lookahead makes any difference. What you are talking about only requires a backreference. Is this an even/odd issue ? Example: `((\w+=\w+)(?:\s?\2)*)`

Comment: `'<a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b r=d c=b c=d e=f>'.match(/(?=(\s*\w+=\w+\s*))\1/g);`

@sln, I found a solution.

Comment: Yeah, but `(?=(\s*\w+=\w+\s*))\1` doesn't do anything except match what you saw in the lookahead, Its the exact same as `(\s*\w+=\w+\s*)` there is absolutely no difference.

Comment: There are features a lookahead can be used for, like bump-along, or single character bump, while looking past that character. This is more advanced.

Comment: I know look a head used simply to understand how everything works.

Comment: @sln, You can answer the question? `"xy".match (/ y?/)`. Why not find y?

Comment: No match, can't find ` ` --------

Comment: @sln, see screenshot: http://savepic.su/5726524.png

Why is that?

Comment: y is optional -- It could match nothing at position 0, so it did. It did match, but it matched the empty string (nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole of this task can't be done with regex but you can use following regex to get all repeats of `a=b` then [find the max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521245/finding-longest-string-in-array) group :

```
/((?:a=b\s?)\1)+/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO1hP7/2)

Comment: `'<a=b a=b a=b a=b a=b r=d c=b c=d e=f>'.match(/(?=(\s*\w+=\w+\s*))\1/g);`