# Array chaining, filter array by typeof primitive and return shortest length element

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeof, chain

My failed attempt to pull out the shortest string from an array filled with different types of primitives. What am I doing wrong? Are there any other wa

```js
var bands = ([30, 'Seconds', 'to', 'Mars', 1, 'Direction', true]);

function tinyString(collection) {
var tinyStr = '';
return collection.
    filter(function (x) {
      return typeof x === 'string' 
    }).
    forEach(function (y) { 
        if (tinyStr > y){
          return tinyStr = y
        } 
    }) 
}

console.log(bands); // --> 'to'
```

Comment: shouldn't you be comparing string `length`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding longest string in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521245/finding-longest-string-in-array)

Comment: Are you trying to compare the lengths of 1 and true as well? Becuase true will be coerced to 1

Comment: @VamshiGudipati I need to filter out the booleans too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on length and type, and return the first one

```js
var bands = ([30, 'Seconds', 'to', 'Mars', 1, 'Direction', true]);

function tinyString(collection) {
    return collection.sort((a,b)=>typeof a === 'string' ? a.length-b.length:1).shift();
}

console.log( tinyString(bands) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

var bands = [30, 'Seconds', 'to', '', 'Mars', 1, 'Direction', true];

```
function tinyString(collection) {
    var xs = '';
    var i = 0;
    collection.forEach(function (x) {
               if (typeof x === 'string' && x != '') {
                   xs = (i == 0) ? x : (x.length < xs.length) ? x : xs;
                   i++;
               }
           });
    return xs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something of this sort.Here the shortest string would 'to'

```js
var bands = ([30, 'Seconds', 'to', 'Mars', 1, 'Direction', true]);
var strArray = bands.filter(function(item) {
  if (typeof item == "string")
    return item
});
var maxLength, shortStr;
strArray.forEach(function(str) {
  var currLength = str.length;
  if (maxLength == undefined || currLength < maxLength) {
    maxLength = currLength;
    shortStr = str;
  }


});

console.log(shortStr);
```

Hope it helps