# Find the longest length of an array item - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find the length of the longest string in the given array. It should return 0 if the array is empty.

So here's my try:

```
function getLengthOfLongestElement(arr) {
  var biggestNum = 0;

 for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] > biggestNum){
        biggestNum = arr[i];
     }
 }
}

var output = getLengthOfLongestElement(['one', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(output); // --> MUST RETURN 5
```

But this one did not work. Any idea or is there any better option to do this?

Comment: The function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding longest string in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521245/finding-longest-string-in-array)

Answer (score 5):

To throw another alternative into the mix: `Math.max` can be fed the lengths as arguments (by mapping them on the input) to get the longest string:

```js
function getLengthOfLongestElement(arr) {
  return Math.max(0,...arr.map(s=>s.length));
}

var output = getLengthOfLongestElement(['one', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Nice but when the input array is empty instead of `0` it returns `-Infinity`

Comment: @Redu true, added an extra 0 argument to prevent that from happening

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently a reducing job and can simply be implemented as follows;

```js
var ss = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ln = ss.reduce((r,s) => r > s.length ? r : s.length, 0);
console.log(ln);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test with `arr[i].length` instead of `arr[i]` and you should return `biggestNum` at the end of your function:

```
function getLengthOfLongestElement(arr) {
  var biggestNum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length > biggestNum) {
      biggestNum = arr[i].length;
    }
  }
  return biggestNum;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function getLengthOfLongestElement(arr) {
  var biggestNum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length > biggestNum) {
      biggestNum = arr[i].length;
    }
  }
  return biggestNum;
}

var output = getLengthOfLongestElement(['one', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the string `length` property. So instead of `arr[i]` it will be `arr[i].length`

```
function getLengthOfLongestElement(arr) {
  var biggestNum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length > biggestNum) {
      biggestNum = arr[i].length;
    }
  }

  return biggestNum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution is using reduce.

```js
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
const maxLength = arr.reduce((acc, item) => Math.max(acc, item.length), 0);

console.log(maxLength)
```

Comment: This would be a good answer, but it does not cover the scenario "It should return 0 if the array is empty." You should pass 0 as the initial value in your reduce function as the second parameter.

Comment: Right you are sir... Just updated it, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

For zero element just check if the array length is zero or not else arr[i].length will return the length of the string

```js
function getLengthOfLongestElement(arr) {
  var biggestNum = 0;
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].length > biggestNum) {
        biggestNum = arr[i].length;
      }

    }
  } else if (arr.length == 0) {
    biggestNum = 0
  }
  return biggestNum

}

var output = getLengthOfLongestElement(['one', 'two', 'three']);
console.log(output);
```