# Return longest string in array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

So I'm trying to find the longest string in an array of strings. I've done a problem similar to this before where I had to return the length of the longest string. The thing is, my code works and returns 11 when it looks like this:

```
var long1= 0;

var plorp = ["bbllkw", "oox", "ejjuyyy", "plmiis", "xxxzgpsssa", "xxwwkktt", "znnnnfqknaz", "qqquuhii", "dvvvwz"];

function longestString(arr){
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i].length > long1){
        long1= arr[i].length;
      }

  }
  return long1;
}
```

but, if I change `long1= arr[i].length;` to `long1 = arr[i];` it just returns `arr[0]` instead. Am I missing something here? The loop seems to be iterating correctly otherwise.

Edit: that is to say, it returns `bbllkw`.

Comment: You are overriding an integer value with a string and trying to use one variable for multiple things. You should keep `long1= arr[i].length` and `return arr[long1]` at the end.

Comment: @the4akman you are incorrect. `long1` contains longest length not index. So `arr[long1]` will very likely be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you must change long declaration to :

```
var long1= '';
```

and in the for loop condition it should be

```
arr[i].length > long1.length
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `reduce` instead:

```js
var plorp = ["bbllkw", "oox", "ejjuyyy", "plmiis", "xxxzgpsssa", "xxwwkktt", "znnnnfqknaz", "qqquuhii", "dvvvwz"];
var longest = plorp.reduce(function(a, b) { 
  return a.length > b.length ? a : b
}, '');
console.log(longest);
```

Or ES6 version:

```js
var plorp = ["bbllkw", "oox", "ejjuyyy", "plmiis", "xxxzgpsssa", "xxwwkktt", "znnnnfqknaz", "qqquuhii", "dvvvwz"];
var longest = plorp.reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b, '');
console.log(longest);
```

Comment: Nice concise ES6 1-liner too: `plorp.reduce((p, c) => p.length > c.length ? p : c)`.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the reply. I was thinking about writing this as ES6 but wasn't sure the OP can use ES6 in his env.... Added this to the answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is great! I'm a bit new to ES6, but it makes sense. Also, I'm a girl :)

Answer (score 3):

***Updated after a user wanted more basic solution***

In here we find the longest length of an array item with `reduce` function, and then filter the array with the elements which have that length with `filter` function. It returns us *multiple* elements if they have the same but longest length

```
var plorp = ['sameLength', 'someoth', 'asfzc', 'sameLLngth'];
    ln = plorp.reduce((r,s) => r > s.length ? r : s.length, 0);


const result = plorp.filter(pl => pl.length == ln);

console.log(result);
```

**Old Answer**

If there are ***more than one*** longest string in the array, it will return an array of them. If there is only one longest, it will return the string, and not an array.

```
var plorp = ["bbllkw", "oox", "ejjuyyy", "plmiis", "xxxzgpsssa", "xxwwkktt", "znnnnfqknaz", "qqquuhii", "dvvvwz"];
var wholeArr = [];

function longestString(arr) {
    var tlength = 0;
    for(var i =0; i < plorp.length; i++){
      if(tlength < plorp[i].length){
        tlength = plorp[i].length;
      }
    }
    for(var j =0; j < plorp.length; j++){
      if(plorp[j].length == tlength){
         wholeArr.push(plorp[j]);
      }
    }
   if(wholeArr.length == 1){
     return wholeArr[0]
   }else{
      return wholeArr
  }
}


console.log(longestString(plorp));
```

Comment: excellent, but is there a way to write it more functional and not so verbose?

Comment: Yes, I have updated it for you @GismoRanas

Comment: I ended up finding my own solution and I wrote it below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> var arr = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "thousand"]
>
> function  getLongestString(arr) 
>   {
>      let longestStringArr = arr.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length).reverse();
>      return longestStringArr[0];
>   }
>
> console.log(getLongestString(arr))

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the length of the strings and then assign the string itself to long1.

```js
var plorp = ["bbllkw", "oox", "ejjuyyy", "plmiis", "xxxzgpsssa", "xxwwkktt", "znnnnfqknaz", "qqquuhii", "dvvvwz"];

function longestString(arr) {
  var long1 = arr[0];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length > long1.length) {
      long1 = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return long1;
}


console.log(longestString(plorp));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you set

```
long1=arr[i];
```

And you compare with length which is integer value.

At first iteration, you compare integer value of 0 with length of first string which of course make the comparison expression result  true and you set

```
 long1=arr[0];
```

For next iteration, `long1` no longer contain integer value but string so comparison between length and `long1` always return false.

That is why you always get first string as result.

You need to initialize `long1` as empty string and use `long1.length` for comparison as suggested by belhadj's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution involves the array's [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and a comparison function, but that can be a "heavy" solution as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> Depending on the compareFunction's nature, this may yield a high
>   overhead. The more work a compareFunction does and the more elements
>   there are to sort, the wiser it may be to consider using a map for
>   sorting.

So, taking the preceding advice, here's one way to obtain the longest string using a map in conjunction with an array's sort method, as follows:

```js
var plorp = ["bbllkw", "oox", "ejjuyyy", "plmiis",
             "xxxzgpsssa", "xxwwkktt", "znnnnfqknaz",
             "qqquuhii", "dvvvwz"];

function getLongestStr() {
  var mapped = plorp.map((el, i) => ({ index: i, length: el }) );
  mapped.sort((a, b) => {

      if (a.length > b.length) {
        return -1;
      }
   
      if (a.length < b.length) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
  });

// DESC order so longest string in 0th element
  return mapped.map((el) => plorp[el.index])[0];
}
console.log( getLongestStr() );
```

Interesting related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521245/finding-longest-string-in-array).

Comment: Using a sort just to find the max is very heavyweight.  See instead the answer from @Dekel, which is probably as clean as it's going to get.