# How to get the longest string in array without similar like values?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays.

```
1: [a, ab, abc, abcde]
2: [a, ab, abc, abcde, abcdefe, axde]
```

in the first array, I used this code to get the longest line.

```
function longestChain(words) {
    // Write your code here
    var xintTOstring = "";
    var result = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < words.length; x++){
        xintTOstring = words[x].toString();

            if (xintTOstring.length > result) {
                result = xintTOstring.length;
            }

    }
    return result;
}
```

but then in the second array, the longest is "axde". because the `abcde` in that array cannot be the longest because it has an equal like value.

I try this code but did not get the expected result. and also the longest line is the `abcdefer`.

question: how can I get the longest line and check if it is valued like equal in the string. I tried this code but did not get the right output.

```
function longestChain(words) {
    // Write your code here
    var xintTOstring = "";
    var result = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < words.length; x++){
        xintTOstring = words[x].toString();
        if (!words[x].toString().inclcudes(xintTOstring)) {
            if (xintTOstring.length > result) {
                result = xintTOstring.length;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

regards

Comment: Your arrays look wierd ‘[{el1, el2}]’, instead of [el1, el2]

Comment: What is this supposed to be: `[{a, ab, abc, abcde, abcdefe, axde}]`? Is it an array of strings? If so it should be `['a', 'ab', 'abc']` etc...

Comment: @MarkMeyer I edited my question. Sorry i am beginner sir

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes sir. That's right

Comment: You need to concat the 2 arrays and look for repeats first. Then find out the length of these repeats before looking for the longest value in length

Comment: Also, what are “equal” strings in your definition.

Comment: Why isn't `abcdefe` the longest with characters `abcdf`?

Comment: So you want to return `abcde` for the first array, then `abcdefe` for the second array?

Comment: @SamuelToh Can you give me example sir? for me to understand the flow of the code.

Comment: My suggestion, show us the question.

Comment: you want to get longest string combining both array or both in different operation??

Comment: Or do you want the one with the most different characters?

Comment: Give us sample input and output values.

Comment: @JackBashford, no sir. the longest line is `axde` because, it does not have an equal like in the arrays. if you count it you have the length of `4` but if you disregard the `abcde` in `abcdefe` you will get only 2 characters. so that means the `axde` is the longest.

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/qo6cvmjn/4/ , do you need something like this??

Comment: I'm sorry @AlexisAbulenciaVillar I don't follow how that works. Could you explain please?

Comment: @SunnyRGupta,  Ok sir. I will give an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding longest string in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521245/finding-longest-string-in-array)

Comment: @Sushil, sort of. but the `abcdefe` has an equal like value sir. and that's `abcde`. so it means the `axde` is the longest line.

Comment: got it, let me try to solve

Answer (score 0):

```
function equalLike(word) {
     // should the equality be checked within the array or in global stream?
}

function longestChain(words) {
    return words.reduce((longest,word) => longest = longest.length > equalLike(word).length ? 
                                                    longest : word,'');
}
```

the longest word acts as the accumulator.

Comment: Please read the question and comments. There is a caveat where strings that include other strings have their length reduced.

Comment: Does not solve the problem. Look at the second case. Expected output is “axde”, but you’re returning “abcdefe”

Comment: the question is so convoluted O.o What in english is an "equal like value" ?

Comment: If the question is not clear, what was the answer trying  to achieve?

Comment: I might have misread it and jumped to the solution based on the title.

Comment: and that, my friend, leads to “bugs”. 

Comment: @DhananjaiPai like `similar` sir?

Comment: @AlexisAbulenciaVillar similar within the same array or in the previous array ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai in the array sir. for example. this value `abcde` and `abcdefe` is equal in `abcde`.so if you remove the `abcde` in the arrays, the `axde` is the longest. because it has a length of 4. but the `abcdefe` when you remove the `abcde` it has only 2 characters left.

Comment: what if there is xabcdef ? will abcde still be "equal like" ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai No Sir

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, each call to longest word should return the longest word not yet found.  Go through each list, keep object of longest words, check against that object, and check substrings against keys

```
const longestWords = {};

const longestChain = function(words) {
  let longestInList = "";

  words.forEach(function(word) {
    if (validLongestWord(word) && word.length > longestInList.length) {
      longestInList = word;
    }
  });

  longestWords[longestInList] = longestInList.length; //maybe handy for sorting later

  return longestInList;
}

const validLongestWord = function(word) {
    if(longestWords[word]) return false;

  return !Object.keys(longestWords).some(key=>key.indexOf(word) >=0);
}

console.log(longestChain(["a", "ab", "abc", "abcde", "abcdefe", "axde"])); //abcdefe
console.log(longestChain(["a", "ab", "abc", "abcde", "abcdefe", "axde"])); //axde
console.log(longestChain(["a", "ab", "abc", "abcde", "abcdefe", "axde"])); //none
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the problem that the OP is trying to solve using JavaScript:

[Longest Character Removal Chain](https://www.muddyengineer.com/2017/01/longest-string-chain-programming-problem-c-solution/)
and
[Interview Questions - String Chain](https://blog.cancobanoglu.net/2016/09/18/interview-questions-string-chain/)

Anyone please feel welcome to edit this answer to provide a solution for the question asked.

```js
var StackOverFlow;
(function(StackOverFlow) {
  var LongestChain = (function() {
    function LongestChain() {}
    LongestChain.main = function(args) {
      // Array of words
      var words = ["a", "ab", "abc", "abcdefe", "axde"];
      console.info(
        "Longest Chain Length : " + LongestChain.longest_chain(words)
      );
    };
    LongestChain.longest_chain = function(w) {
      if (null == w || w.length < 1) {
        return 0;
      }
      var maxChainLen = 0;
      var words = w.slice(0).slice(0);
      var wordToLongestChain = {};
      for (var index7809 = 0; index7809 < w.length; index7809++) {
        var word = w[index7809];
        {
          if (maxChainLen > word.length) {
            continue;
          }
          var curChainLen =
            LongestChain.find_chain_len(word, words, wordToLongestChain) + 1;
          /* put */ wordToLongestChain[word] = curChainLen;
          maxChainLen = Math.max(maxChainLen, curChainLen);
        }
      }
      return maxChainLen;
    };
    LongestChain.find_chain_len = function(word, words, wordToLongestChain) {
      var curChainLen = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        var nextWord = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
        if (words.indexOf(nextWord) >= 0) {
          if (wordToLongestChain.hasOwnProperty(nextWord)) {
            curChainLen = Math.max(
              curChainLen,
              /* get */ (function(m, k) {
                return m[k] ? m[k] : null;
              })(wordToLongestChain, nextWord)
            );
          } else {
            var nextWordChainLen = LongestChain.find_chain_len(
              nextWord,
              words,
              wordToLongestChain
            );
            curChainLen = Math.max(curChainLen, nextWordChainLen + 1);
          }
        }
      }
      return curChainLen;
    };
    return LongestChain;
  })();
  StackOverFlow.LongestChain = LongestChain;
  LongestChain["__class"] = "StackOverFlow.LongestChain";
})(StackOverFlow || (StackOverFlow = {}));
StackOverFlow.LongestChain.main(null);
```