# Finding Longest & Shortest word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

One of the question is to find longest word in a string & another one is to find the shortest word in a string.

I am trying to figure out the difference between solving them. I understand everything except why is "longestlength =0"  for the longestlength instead of "longestlength = newString[0].length." I tried solving it with that and the output is undefined. Likewise, for the "shortestLength" if I initialize it with "0" instead of "newString[0].length" I get undefined but I don't understand the reason behind it.

```
//code for longest string

 function longestWord(string) { 
let newString =string.split(" ");
let longestWord;
let longestlength= 0;
for(let i=0; i<newString.length; i++){
if(newString[i].length > longestlength){
  longestlength = newString[i].length;
  longestWord= newString[i];
 }
  }
 return longestWord;
  }

 //code for shortest string
  function shortestWord(string) {
 var stringArray = string.split(" ");  
  var shortestWord;
  var shortestLength = stringArray[0].length; 
  for(var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
   if(stringArray[i].length < shortestLength){
  shortestLength = stringArray[i].length;   
  shortestWord = stringArray[i];            
  }
    }
return shortestWord;
  }
```

Comment: In `longestWord` function it makes sense to initialize the `longestlength` variable with 0, because it's going to be replaced with the first element of the array with length greater than 0. In `shortestWord` you assume that the first word is the shortest only to verify that in the subsequent for loop iterations. However, I think there's a mistake there, namely `shortestWord` should be initialized with the value of `stringArray[0]`.

Comment: I'm curious if your input text has any punctuation.  If it does, then splitting on `" "` is not necessarily going to give you an accurate word break.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding longest string in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521245/finding-longest-string-in-array)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be solved in one line using `reduce`.

Longest word:

```
string.split(' ').reduce((acc, cur) => acc.length >= cur.length ? acc : cur);
```

Shortest word:

```
string.split(' ').reduce((acc, cur) => acc.length <= cur.length ? acc : cur);
```

**Here's why your code might not work**: In `shortestWord`, you set the current shortest length to the length of the first word in the array, but you don't set the shortest word to the first word in the array, it is still undefined. If the first word in the array happens to be the shortest word, no word is shorter, therefore no word will ever be assigned to `shortestWord` and the function will return `undefined`.

**Solution**: Replace

```
var shortestWord;
```

with

```
var shortestWord = stringArray[0];
```

Comment: This is a great way to solve the problem of finding min/max of strings, but doesn't help OP with his (admittedly poor) question of why the code isn't working. Fancy one liners won't be good in the long run for most people trying to learn.

Comment: @SvenWritesCode You're right. I added an explanation.

Comment: Awesome. If you want to add the answer to the other question: "why is "longestlength =0" for the longestlength instead of "longestlength = newString[0].length."" Iff the first element of the split string is the longest word `if(newString[i].length > longestlength)` never evaluates to  true and will return `longestWord` as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`longestlength` has always have to match `longestWord`. If you set the length, but not the word itself, and if the length is actually the longest one, `longestWord` gets returned although it is yet empty.

To avoid such mistakes, just keep the word itself, and check its length with `.length`:

```
  function longest(words) {
    let longest;
    for(const word of words.split(" "))
      if(!longest || word.length > longest.length) // swap this to get the "shortest"
        longest = word;
    return longest;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function longest(str){
    return str.split(" ").reduce((a,b)=> b.length >= a.length ? b : a,'')
}

function shortest(str){
    return str.split(" ").reduce((a, b)=>a.length <= b.length ? a : b, '')
}
```