# How to obtain the longest words in a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find the way to obtain the longest words of each array:

```
var carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
var herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
var omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];
```

Then I create a multidimensional-array:
 `var animals = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];`

In order to obtain the longest words of each array I do this:

```js
var carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
var herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
var omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];
var animals = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];

function longestAnimals() {
  var longest = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < animals[i].length; j++) {
      if (animals[i][j].length > longest.length) {
        longest = animals[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return longest;
}

console.log(longestAnimals());
```

My code returns the longest word of all the array, it shows only elephant. What can I do to obtain shark, elephant, and monkey.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding longest string in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521245/finding-longest-string-in-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you are looping and finding only one value.

It is needed to make the `longest` as array and whenever the `j` loop finishes, push the item for that sub array as follows.

```js
var carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
var herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
var omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];

var animals = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];
function longestAnimals() {
  var longest = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    var longestItem = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < animals[i].length; j++) {
      if (animals[i][j].length > longestItem.length) {
        longestItem = animals[i][j];
      }
    }
    longest.push(longestItem);
  }
  return longest;
}
console.log(longestAnimals());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Make a function that gets the longest word in one array, then map it onto the other functions:

```js
function longest(arr) {
    let longest = "";
    for (const ele of arr) {
        if (ele.length > longest.length) {
            longest = ele;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}

function longestInEach(arr) {
    return arr.map(v => longest(v));
}

const carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
const herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
const omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];
const animals = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];

console.log(longestInEach(animals)) // ["shark", "elephant", "monkey"]
```

Answer (score 3):

One line of functional solution using `Array.prototype.sort()` and `Array.prototype.map()` method. Just sort each inner array by string length in descending order and return the first element of each array.

```js
const carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
const herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
const omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];
const animals = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];

const longestAnimals = (arr) =>
  arr.map((x) => x.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0]);

console.log(longestAnimals(animals));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Array.prototype.reduce` to return the longest string in each array:

```js
var carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
var herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
var omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];
var animals = [carnivores, herbivores, omnivores];

var longestString = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(
    function (a, b) { return a.length > b.length ? a : b; }
  );
}

var longest = animals.map(function(arr) {
  return longestString(arr);
})

console.log(longest);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the input arrays using per array sorting to find the longest word:

```js
const carnivores = ['lion', 'shark', 'wolve', 'puma', 'snake'];
const herbivores = ['elephant', 'giraffe', 'gacelle', 'hippo', 'koala'];
const omnivores = ['human', 'monkey', 'dog', 'bear', 'pig'];

console.log(longestWords(carnivores, herbivores, omnivores));

function longestWords(...arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce( (acc, arr) => 
    [...acc, arr.sort( (a, b) => b.length - a.length).shift()], []);
}
```